# Counter inside multiple recursion

Tags: python-2.7, dynamic-programming

So I am writing a code which have multiple recursive function calls. And I want to increment a counter whenever some condition is met.

```py
def funct(n):
   return rec_func(a,b)

def rec_func(x,y):
    global counter
    if <conditiona met>:
        counter += 1
    rec_func(m,n)
    rec_func(j,k)
    return counter

counter = 0
print funct(q)
```

The above code does what i need. But i cant have the "counter" defined as global because of some constraints where the code is run. Is there any other way to achieve this with out the global variable "counter"

**NOTE:
The recursive function is called twice within that function. So I need a way to supply the count from one to the next.**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really want to make the variable "counter" as global, the just make it as an argument that you pass to your function's parameter
In this code, I call the function "call_recursive" which calls the "recursive_function" with the argument x = 5 and counter = 0 and the function will call itself 5 times and x will decrement. X will stop after it has reach 0 and it returns the counter. I hope it helps.

```
def call_recursive(x):
    counter = 0
    return recursive_function(x, counter)

def recursive_function(x, counter):
    if(x != 0):
        counter += 1
        return recursive_function(x - 1, counter)
    else:
        return counter


x = 5
print(call_recursive(x))
```

Comment: This code should work. But if look at my code you can see that the function "rec_func" is called twice inside the same function. So what happens is the counter gets reset to the top of the stack of first call.